# Present a specific ViewController from the TabBarController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, unusernotificationcenter

I want to open a specific `ViewController` from the `TabBarController` whenever a *local notification* is fired and their custom action is performed. I have used following line of *code*:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case "first":
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.first()
        })
    case "second":
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.second()
        })
    default:
        break
    }


    completionHandler()
}
```

So it's a `first()` *function*:

```
 func first() {


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Root") as! UITabBarController
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! UINavigationController

    tabBarController.present(navigationController, animated: true) { 

    }

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Second *function*: `second()`

```
func second() {


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Root") as! UITabBarController
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Second") as! UINavigationController

    tabBarController.present(navigationController, animated: true) {

    }

    self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

And it's works well, but I cannot open the second `ViewController` while the first one is presented and the second *notification* is fired: In the console: **Warning attempt to present ViewController...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

Or this:

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![1]
```

Where **1** can be any of the `viewcontrollers` presented by your `tabBarController`

Comment: It's seems to useless. It's returns only 1

Comment: It doesn't have to return anything. If you set selectedIndex to any number, the tab bar will change its tab to the index selected. If you set selectedIndex = 0, you will be switch to the first tab. selectedIndex = 1, second tab. And so on

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have not any experience with the UITabBarController class.

Answer (score 1):

I had run into a similar issue and changing the `selectedIndex` did not work for me. Depending on the requirements of your project you can *instantiate* your `ViewController` and add it as a `Subview` and move to that `Subview`. When youre done make sure to remove that `Subview`.

```
let replyView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("replyView")
    self.addChildViewController(replyView!)
    self.view.addSubview(replyView!.view)
    replyView!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Inside whichever action you desire to change the `ViewController` with. If its a button action then call the above code inside the buttons action.